# How is input type="date" displayed in browsers which do not support html5

Tags: html, input

I want to use  in my program.
I want to know, how they will be displayed in browsers which do not support HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As every other newly introduced input types by `HTML5`, as an:

```
<input type="text" />
```

See [HTML5 - input=number and incompatible browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521445/html5-input-number-and-incompatible-browsers) accepted answer.